# AutoCompleteTextView and EditText is null in other activity

Tags: android

I have activity_password_change.xml and PasswordChangeActivity.  It's look like this:

```
public class PasswordChangeActivity extends BaseActivity {

private AutoCompleteTextView mNiu;
private EditText mPassword;
private TextView mCurrentPassword;
private TextView mNewPassword;
private TextView mRepeatPassword;
private Button mChange;
private PasswordChangeViewModel mPasswordChangeViewModel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_password_change);

    mNiu = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.NIU);
    mPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    mCurrentPassword = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.current_password);
    mNewPassword = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.new_password);
    mRepeatPassword = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.repeat_password);
    mChange = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Change);

    mPasswordChangeViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(PasswordChangeViewModel.class);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);

    mChange.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mPasswordChangeViewModel.changePassword(mNiu, mPassword, mCurrentPassword, mNewPassword, mRepeatPassword);
        }
    });
}
```

....

```
void changePassword(AutoCompleteTextView niu, EditText password, TextView currentPassword, TextView newPassword, TextView repeatPassword){
    if(password.getText().toString().equals(currentPassword.getText().toString()) &&
            newPassword.getText().toString().equals(repeatPassword.getText().toString())){
        int yourNiu = Integer.parseInt(niu.getText().toString());
        if (yourNiu < 10) {
            mRepository.changePassword(yourNiu, newPassword.getText().toString());
        } else if(yourNiu >= 10 && yourNiu < 20) {
        }else{
        }
    }
}
```

and I use R.id.NIU and R.id.password which are from other .xml file (activity_login.xml). My problem is that password.getText().toString () is null. Is there any uncomplicated solution?

Answer (score 0):

> and I use R.id.NIU and R.id.password which are from other .xml file
>   (activity_login.xml)

This is where your problem is. Just create this views in activity_password_change.xml

P.S. You can't use views from one view hierarchy in another view hierarchy.

**UPD**

I assume that you're starting PasswordChangeActivity from LoginActivity.
Put this code in LoginActivity instead of code which launches PasswordChangeActivity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, PasswordChangeActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("pass", mPassword.getText.toString());
intent.putExtra("niu", mNiu.getText.toString());
startActivity(intent);
```

And in PasswordChangeActivity right after setContentView() method

```
String pass = getIntent().getStringExtra("pass");
String niu = getIntent().getStringExtra("niu");
```

Delete this lines as you don't need it anymore

```
mNiu = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.NIU);
mPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
```

Change changePassword() signature to

```
void changePassword(String niu, String password, String currentPassword, String newPassword, String repeatPassword)
```

*P.P.S. Don't pass views to ViewModel, only data as it could lead to memory leaks*

Comment: I can not create them here, the user logs in and in another activity is to be able to change the password. I want to read the password given when logging in to check if it is definitely the same user (and not that someone forgot to log out)

Comment: Maybe it can be checked somehow differently and I just come from the wrong side, please help me

Comment: I have a slightly different structure, but thanks a lot. You helped me a lot. I would like to give you 1 but unfortunately I am new and I have too little reputation. Thanks also for the tips, it means a lot to me :)